# get OpenGL error GL_INVALID_OPERATION when call glDrawArrays on macOS

Tags: macos, opengl

I got some problem about OGL in macOS, as the following sample, it works well in my win system but get error at API **glPushAttrib**, **glDrawArrays**, and **glPopAttrib** and get **GL_INVALID_OPERATION** each. Any idea about this?

I had read some topic about the issue but seems not work on macOS and compare with win system.
My mac is OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 with compiler Xcode version 6.4

```c++
//gen a texture
glGenTextures(1, &FilteredTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FilteredTexture);
printf("Start glTexImage2D FilteredTexture...");
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, TexInterFormat, cols, rows, 0, TexFormat, DataType, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//gen a Renderbuffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &GlRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GlRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, cols, rows);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

//gen a Framebuffer & attach
glGenFramebuffers(1, &GlFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GlFramebuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, FilteredTexture, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, GlRenderbuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

//gen shaderas program (ignore detail here)
program = loadProgramFromFile("empty.vert", "depth.frag", "quad.geom");

//do the computation
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GlFramebuffer);
const static GLuint attachment_bufferss[] = { static_cast<GLuint>(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0) };
glDrawBuffers(1, attachment_bufferss);
glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT);  //get GL_INVALID_OPERATION here
glViewport(0, 0, cols, rows);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);      
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(1);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);  //get GL_INVALID_OPERATION here
glDrawBuffers(1, attachment_bufferss);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glUseProgram(0);
glPopAttrib();   //get GL_INVALID_OPERATION here
glFinish();
```

full code can be downloaded here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au9Donvb28A9hgeor0v94Q5hKc0e

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you using? If I'm not mistaken, `glPushAttrib` is deprecated unless using Compatibility profile, but macOS only supports Core profile.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine I use OGL 3.3 core in my shader, is that ok?

Comment: It is not ok to use deprecated/removed features such as `glPushAttrib` in Core profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors occur because you're trying to use deprecated functions (`glPushAttrib`, `glPopAttrib`) in Core profile. To fix this, replace line

```
glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT);
```

with

```
GLint vp [4];
glGetIntegerv (GL_VIEWPORT, vp);
```

and

```
glPopAttrib();
```

with

```
glViewport( vp[0], vp[1], vp[2], vp[3] );
```

The code first copies your current viewport into an array, then restores the viewport from the array.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help! unfortunately, I still have the same error on  glDrawArrays after modification based on your suggestion. Do have have any idea about this? or the glDrawArrays should have some other way to modify on Core profile?

Comment: @Robin Have you created and bound a VAO using `glGenVertexArrays`? It's required for drawing methods in Core profile.

Comment: @ SurvivalMachine I have not use the VAO here. The error will not appear when I create a VAO for it, unfortunately, the GLSL result within the FBO: FilteredTexture (GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0) is still incorrect. Is that possible to keep the FBO used in core profile? or should I  have to do something for it?

Comment: The issue had been solved after another VAO is generated, thank you for the help!